# Implement Hiptest action words in JavaScript

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, test-planning

I have set up a test plan in [Hiptest](https://hiptest.net/) and am working on the setup/ teardown for my tests using JavaScript. I have hit a blocker with my goal of using Hiptest with just JavaScript frameworks (mocha and nightwatchjs) in that I can't find out how to modify and sync my action words with Hiptest in JavaScript. The default in the browser is Ruby, but I can't see any option to change this.

Does anyone know what my options are if I don't wish to use Ruby to define my action words?

Answer (score 1):

The code you see in the action words page is not Ruby (even if it is close to it). The code is Hiptest's language.
The automation should not be done inside Hiptest but in the skeleton code generated by hiptest-publisher and committed to the same repository than the code of the app you are testing.

Comment: Ah thanks for clearing that up (about the language). I guess in response to that, what I want to know is where does hiptest fit into the test automation stack - is it just for planning and has a nifty test file generation tool? If so, after that does it just sync test results back or more than that?

Comment: For the automation, it's hiptest-publisher that does the job (generating the code and also pushing the results back to Hiptest).
I've sent you a link in the in-app chat where you'll be able to see a webinar about automation and hiptest that could answer some of your questions.